# Beginner- Bevel Question

Tags: bevel

Hi Blender Community,

I have a noob question. I've noticed that when I bevel a cube, the bevel turned out to be evenly distributed. However, when beveling a rectangular box, I am noticing the bevel is scaling in proportion to the long and short length of the box.

I figured that if I then try and rotate them locally, it might do the trick. But I've come to realize that unless there is a menu that I can punch in the numbers directly, I wouldn't be able to know for sure if the angle is exact.

If you all can help shed some light on a method that worked for you, please let me know!

I'll attach a photo so that the problem is easier to understand.

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data/7349#7349

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the scale of the object, right? It will make the whole object being transformed. While bevel, as an operator, only work in mesh edit mode. It wont consider the scale of the object. (<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> can apply the scale)

[image]

And almost every operator(Redo Last operator) will give you a floating dock to tweak your option in the left-bottom corner. If it doesn't appeared, try hitting <kbd>F9</kbd> (<kbd>F6</kbd> for Blender 2.79 and below).

[image]

And if you want more control over the bevel, try out bevel modifier:

[image]

You can custom a lot of effect with edge weight, one should always consider using modifier unless the task is not complicate and don't need further modification.

Comment: Ah thanks for explaining the modifier! I didnt know that was a thing!

To answer your question, It seems that it even does that for a cube now... so all my bevels are not even. I wish i can post a photo to show you but i dont see a attachment section.... 

To describe it the best I can, the bevel even for the cube, is appearing to be cutting in deeper in one area over another. In other words, if observed at a top ortho view, the square should look like an even ocatgon. However, in mine, it looks like an uneven octagon.

Comment: Edit* I added a photo of the original question. to explain my situation! Thanks for the quick response btw!

Comment: @Cox So you need to undo those bevel? If you're not using modifier. It will be almost impossible to recover it. Careful to bevel anything with operator. Another question, did you **apply the scale**?

Comment: I figured it out! I apologize for making you repeat yourself twice. I didn't quite understand the situation and the reasoning behind what I was facing. 

Originally i thought you were pointing out if I beveled and then scaled it. 
Now I understand that if I were to Scale in Object Mode, the scale would skew the information. Hence when I jump back into edit mode, the bevel will distort to the scale referencing the scale from    "Object Mode"  . In order to avoid this, I will need to   "Apply Scale"   by   "Ctrl+A"   and press "Scale". This makes so much more sense now!